# Python script with executable permission says "Command Not Found"

Tags: python, shell, executable, tcsh

I have a python script abc.py. Inside a shell script file, I call it `./abc.py`

Inside abc.py, at the top, I have `#!/usr/bin/python`

`test -x abc.py && echo true || echo false` return true

On executing the shell script, it says `./abc.py: Command not found.`

It works if I call it as `python ./abc.py` instead of just `./abc.py`

The issue is only with this abc.py file that I created today. The older python scripts in the same directory with different purpose and names work without any issue.

I have referred the correct path of the file BTW. What could be the issue?

Comment: You're checking for `ABC.PY` but you're running `abc.py`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry....typo....I actually had a proper file name. Just to post it as a question here on SO...I edited it to abc.py.. Have Changed it

Comment: Please avoid editing output before posting it. Instead, change your code/example so that it outputs something you can post, and then copy-paste it directly (ie. edit->run->post instead of run->edit->post). It seems like it shouldn't matter, but see [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) for all the various tiny details that can make all the difference.

Comment: This time you're checking for `abc.PY` but you're running `abc.py`. Please create a new example in a new file that you're comfortable posting in its entirety. If the problem *is* with your filename, then you're asking an impossible question because you hid the source of the problem

Comment: I understand..sorry for the issues

Comment: Yeah, I have edited the question and what I have in the question exactly replicates my issue

Comment: Try chmod +x ~path to ~/abc.py

Comment: Yes did that already

Comment: post the whole contents of your file.

Comment: Try changing your first line to this: #!/usr/bin/env python    
.By default its 3, if not then specify like pyhton2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tcsh`, this happens when the interpreter is invalid:

```
$ cat foo
#!/invalid

$ tcsh -c './foo'
./foo: Command not found.

$ bash -c './foo'
bash: ./foo: /invalid: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This could be for several reasons. Perhaps your path is wrong for your system:

```
% type python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
```

in this case the script needs to start with `#!/usr/local/bin/python` instead.

Alternatively, the script could have Windows line endings (carriage returns):

```
$ cat -v foo
#!/usr/bin/python^M
...^M
```

In this case, save it with Unix line endings instead.

Comment: type doesn't exist. I did 'which python'...It returns that exact path I have listed. Moreover the older python scripts with the same header work. Only the newer one doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user3219492 Do `cat -v yourfile` and see if the line ends with `^M`. If it does, resave your file with Unix line endings instead of DOS ones.

Comment: Thanks...can you please add the comment as an answer...I will accept it

Comment: Probably because I was using Sublime text editor from Windows to create the python script on remote system

Answer (score 0):

Trying to replicate your setup as follows:

1. File: `asdf.py`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   print("Hello World")
   ```
2. File: `asdf.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ -x asdf.py ]; then ./asdf.py ; else echo "Arrrrgh. File does not exist or does not have executable permisions"; fi
   ```
3. Now I save the files in the same directory, e.g. the Desktop, make them executable and run the `shell` script from the terminal.

   ```
   usr@cmptr $ chmod +x asdf.{py,sh}
   usr@cmptr $ ls -la asdf.{py,sh}
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 usr usr 613 Mar 15 22:22 asdf.py
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 usr usr  56 Mar 15 22:14 asdf.sh
   usr@cmptr $ ./asdf.sh
   Hello World
   ```

Now, maybe I have misunderstood your setup but this should work just fine.